# Extracting Named Entity from Input Utterance in python using regex

Tags: python, regex

Say I have some strings

```
"Open Youtube"
"Install PlayStore App"
"Go to Call of Duty app"
```

Now I have a `rules.list` file which contains all the rules in it to extract the named entity out of the above commands.

Say the contents of rules.list file is like this

```
app install (.*)    1
app install app (.*)    1
app install the (.*) app    1
app uninstall the app (.*)  1
app uninstall app (.*)  1
app uninstall the (.*) app  1
app go to (.*) app  1
app download (.*)   1
app download (.*) app   1
app download app (.*)   1
app download the app (.*)   1
app download the (.*) app   1
app install the app (.*)    1
app open the (.*) app   1
app open (.*)   1
app uninstall (.*)  1
app launch (.*) app 1
app launch (.*) 1
```

Is there any way I can use this `rules.list` file in python to extract the Named Entities from my sentences, so that I will have `Youtube`, `PlayStore` , `Call of Duty` as my output?

Comment: can you explain a bit..

Comment: It is actually (.*) in the rules.list file

Comment: What I was trying to do is that 

`import re | txt = "Siri launch Myntra" | x = re.findall("launch (.*)", txt)` but this will make the code excess long in python as there are various rules to check

Comment: The above script will give output `'Myntra` which is an app name, but it will be much more helpful if instead of writing this as hardcode we can refer to the rules.list file and extract the named entity from there..

Answer (score 1):

If you strip the rules from the start "app " and the end "   1" then you get a re-expression. The (.*) will return a group containing the wanted value.

A bit tricky are the capitals which you use in the strings but not in the rules.
Because of that I make the string lowercase before using re.

```
rules = [
    "app install (.*)    1",
    "app install app (.*)    1",
    "app install the (.*) app    1",
    "app uninstall the app (.*)  1",
    "app uninstall app (.*)  1",
    "app uninstall the (.*) app  1",
    "app go to (.*) app  1",
    "app install the app (.*)    1",
    "app open the (.*) app   1",
    "app open (.*)   1",
    "app launch (.*) 1",
    ]

for rule in rules:
    rule = rule[4:-1].strip()
    # print(rule)

    for string in strings:

        result = re.search(rule, string.lower())

        if result:
            print('-----------------------------')
            print(f'rule   - {rule}')
            print(f'string - {string}')
            print(f'result - {result.group(1)}')
```

Output

```
-----------------------------
rule   - install (.*)
string - Install PlayStore App
result - playstore app
-----------------------------
rule   - go to (.*) app
string - Go to Call of Duty app
result - call of duty
-----------------------------
rule   - open (.*)
string - Open Youtube
result - youtube
```

I think this should get you started.